# Pain Point in Bicep curl

Tags: exercise, muscle-soreness, biceps

I am doing bicep curls standard nothing special, But I don't feel muscle soreness in middle of biceps, i fell it near lower end of it, near elbow one. is it normal or am I doing curls wrong?

Comment: Is the pain around the muscle, or the tendons? You should be able to tell the difference by probing the sore area.

Comment: Stop curling, do compound lifts. https://www.physioadvisor.com.au/injuries/elbow-forearm/biceps-tendonitis/

Comment: @EricKaufman Not the best advice. While compound lifts are superior, there is no reason OP, or anyone for that matter, should **never** curl. If you meant stop *temporarily*, then my apologies.

Comment: My arms are bigger than any guy in my gym curling in front of the mirror and I never curl. Unless you're a body builder they do nothing except limit available volume in more valuable exercises. Clip a 45lb to a chain and knock out some pullups: plenty big arms.

Comment: We can't tell you what might be causing pain over the internet. You're best bet is a qualified trainer near you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant say if you're doing the curls wrong without seeing your form. However if you **feel pain**, then yes you are doing something wrong and should watch videos on proper form.

On the other hand, If you feel like its only targeting a certain part of your bicep, try to add more variety of workouts, try different types of curls such as hammer, seated, etc and see if that helps.

Also adding compound movements to your workout routine, as suggested above, is always a good idea for muscle growth.